# Scrape livechat till the end of stream with selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, youtube

I'm trying to scrape the youtube livechat. I need to save all old and incoming messages. For this purpose i use a css selector and a infinite loop to accomplish this, however this results in duplicate entries and previous messages being omitted. What is the proper way to do this? The target url is the first commandline argument.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import requests
from requests_html import HTMLSession
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import os,re,sys

def parseyt():
        chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
        chrome_options.add_argument('--executable_path="chromedriver.exe"') 
        chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
        chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
        chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
        chrome_bin = os.getenv('GOOGLE_CHROME_SHIM', None)
        is_local = os.getenv('IS_LOCAL', None)
        chromedriver_path = r'chromedriver.exe'
        service_log_path = "{}/chromedriver.log".format('\.')
        service_args = ['"--verbose", "--log-path=scrape.log"']
        chromedriver_path = 'chromedriver.exe'
        chrome_options.binary_location = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Chromium\Application\chrome.exe'
        browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver_path,chrome_options=chrome_options,service_args=service_args)
        url = sys.argv[1]
        url = url.replace(r'watch?',r'live_chat?')
        print(url)
        browser.get(url)
        browser.implicitly_wait(1)
        while True:
                innerHTML = browser.execute_script("return document.body.innerHTML")
                chats = []
                for chat in browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('yt-live-chat-text-message-renderer'):
                        author_name = chat.find_element_by_css_selector("#author-name").get_attribute('innerHTML')
                        message = chat.find_element_by_css_selector("#message").get_attribute('innerHTML')
                        author_name_encoded = author_name.encode('utf-8').strip()
                        message_encoded = message.encode('utf-8').strip()
                        print(message+" "+author_name+"\n")
        browser.quit()
        return chats
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use YouTube API instead.

Comment: I'm interested in learning web scraping and selenium not in youtube itself.